# You cannot drink it by itself

Tags: grammar, reflexives

Is this usage of *by itself* grammatical? I know it's OK in the following
sentences:

Will the dog be safe left in the car *by itself*? The door seemed to open
all *by itself*. The computer shuts off *by itself* if you don't use 
it. The house stood *by itself* at the end of the street.

But in all these cases we've got a subject doing something *by itself*
whereas in our sentence *by itself* refers to *it* which is not a
subject but a direct object. Shouldn't it be rephrased: *It cannot be
drunk by itself* or *It cannot be being drunk by itself*?

Comment: I disagree with "in all these cases we've got a subject doing something". In the first case "Will it be safe to leave the dog in the car by itself" clearly makes the dog the object. The dog is not doing anything, you are.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but anyway the dog is a subject of the passive construction, so in a sense it's doing the being a subject of the passive construction )))

Comment: The title phrasing is fine, and so is your first suggestion, but not **It cannot be being drunk by itself.**

Comment: I agree it seems rather awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four examples you give of ***by itself***, divide into two pairs.

The first and last are the same idiom, and the second and third are the same.

So if I say "The dog/house was by itself", it means it was alone. "By itself" is another term for "alone".

"The door opened by itself" means that it had no assistance from any person or thing in opening. Again "by itself" means "alone".

Hence ***by itself*** (alone) is simply an adverbial phrase describing how the dog was, or how the door opened.

Comment: I'm quite aware of these two meanings. My question is about a phrasing "X + transitive verb + direct object + by itself". Is it OK to say, for example, _You can't eat it by itself, it requires some ingredients to be added_? It sounds a bit odd to me, I'd put it as _It can't be eaten by itself, it requires..._ and so on.

Comment: @MvLog Both "You can't eat it by itself" and "It can't be eaten by itself" are idiomatic. Both are in everyday use and mean the same thing.

Comment: I suppose by default one would understand [*You can't be married by yourself*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22be+married+by+yourself%22) as meaning that you need at least one other person ***to whom you can get married***. But even though none of those instances in Google Books relate to the possible alternative interpretation, I'm sure somebody somewhere would have used this phrasing with the meaning *You can't conduct your own marriage ceremony (someone else must officiate).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Until reading your comment it hadn't occurred to me that "It can't be eaten by itself" was potentially ambiguous. Unlikely, you might say, but with "they can't be eaten by themselves" it does introduce the spectre of cannibalism.

Comment: Lowering the tone somewhat, I found [*this pussy won't be eaten by itself*](http://www.tengaged.com/blog/Athena/7444048/this-pussy-wont-be-eaten-itself), which I assume equates to *It takes two to "tango"* (in an oral sex context), as with irate parent to teenage offspring: *I wish you'd tidy your room sometimes. Your bed won't make itself, you know!* That ***by itself = alone, unaided*** sense [is actually quite common](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22won%27t+eat+itself%22) in facetious usages with the general sense *Dig in! This [food] won't eat itself!*